# Don't understand Character.digit in Java

Tags: java, character

I'm not sure I understand what this method does. Can someone explain ?
All I know, from what I read, is that "This method returns the numeric value represented by the character in the specified radix."
I'm not sure what a radix is and what it represents. According to the description of what is being returned, I assumed this method gets a character and returns the numeric value of it in the ASCII table, but I guesses that's not true ?

Comment: Why not [try a few examples](http://ideone.com/mW8maR) first, to get a feel for what it might be doing?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Comment: Yup, this question is essentially "what does 'radix' mean?", which is (a) off-topic, and (b) trivial to answer with Google.

Comment: Personally, I find it useful for writing hex Strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you familiar with numerical bases?

For example, '3' in base 10 is equal to 3, '101' in base 2 is equal to 5 in base 10, etc.

That's essentially what `Character.digit` does -- it takes a character, a specified base, and returns the numerical value in base 10.

If you provide it with a value greater then the specified base (for example, `Character.digit('3', 2);`, it'll just return -1, signifying an invalid value.

Comment: so why the input '3' and 2 won't return 11 ? I understand that it returns -1 if the value greater than the base but whats wrong with it ?

Comment: @user3497284 '3' is never a valid number in base 2. If I gave you a sequence of numbers '1A3F' and told you that this was in base 10, you would think that I'm crazy. 'A' and 'F' are not valid digits in base 10 (though they might be valid in other bases such as hexadecimal, for example). Same thing with base 2 -- only '0' and '1' are considered valid digits. Base 2 is binary (on or off), and it doesn't make sense to have a 3rd value.

Comment: oh I thought that if its base 2 (binary) then 3 = 00000011 so again I think I missed what the function is doing

Comment: @user3497284 The function is going the other way around. It takes a character in a specified base, and converts it to base 10. Basically, `0011` (base 2) is EQUAL to `3` (base 10), but `3` is not a valid number in (base 2).

Answer (score 0):

The method isDigit is true of the character and the Unicode decimal digit value of the character (or its single-character decomposition) is less than the specified radix. In this case the decimal digit value is returned.

Comment: suppose if the digit is less than radix value returns the digit value or else returns -1